# Programmatically remove coupon from subscription/order

Tags: php, woocommerce

How can I programmatically remove a coupon from a subscription/order?

This is what I've tried but when running it, it doesn't seem to remove the coupon, where am I going wrong?

```
    $subscription = new WC_Subscription( $_REQUEST['sub_id'] );
    $coupon_code = $_REQUEST['voucher_code'];
    $coupon = new WC_Coupon( $coupon_code );
    $subscription->remove_coupon( $coupon );
```

The flip side of that was adding a coupon which worked fine:

```
      $subscription->add_coupon( $coupon_code,$coupon_amount,'0' );
      $subscription->set_total( $subscription->get_total() - $coupon_amount );
      $subscription->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

The **`remove_coupon`** method parameter is the coupon code, not the object.

Try this:

```
$subscription->remove_coupon( 'coupon_code' );
```

Where *`coupon_code`* is the name of the coupon that the customer applied to the cart or checkout.

Here you will find the documentation: https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-abstracts-abstract-wc-order.html#source-view.1187

Comment: I think that'd work if I was doing it via the cart or checkout, but I'm programmatically doing it on the my account section where I just want to add/remove via a custom form. `remove_coupon` seems to be a cart/checkout function as was `apply_coupon` (the alternative was `add_coupon`)

Comment: This: https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-abstracts-abstract-wc-order.html#source-view.1187 is a method of the `WC_Abstract_Order` class. While this: https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-class-wc-cart.html#source-view.1835 is a method of the `WC_Cart` class. **Both require the coupon code *(and not the object instance)* as a parameter**.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way around this, I just needed to loop over each coupon:

```
      $coupons = $subscription->get_items( 'coupon' );

      // Remove the coupon line.
      $strcode = strtolower($coupon_code);
        foreach ( $coupons as $coupon ) {
        if($coupon->get_code() == $strcode){
          $subscription->remove_coupon( $coupon->get_code() );
        }
      }
```